# How to run a node app after production build by WebPack when output is index.html?

Tags: node.js, webpack, pm2

***Updated for further clarification:
Thanks much for taking the time to reply. Running 'npm run build' (I'm using the Vuetify/Webpack template) created an index.html and a directory named 'static' with the respective html, css, and js (in 'dist' directory). The question is - how can I run this in production using node or pm2 (for example, 'pm2 start myapp.js')?

Doing some further research and testing, the 'npm run build' built as static. It was my lack of understanding how vue-cli was to build for production (via WebPack) (vue-cli builds static meant to be served via web server). Doing further testing, I can load and bring up my app on a couple local Linux servers (the static content running on one servers, while MongoDB and API running on another server (API running with pm2)). Also, I was able to bring it up on AWS S3 (as static). I think I have my answer now. Thanks much for your time.

***From Original Post:
How to run the following node app in production? Webpack build produced an index.html (I assume as it's using html-webpack-plugin). I can view the site if I run under a web server (e.g., nginx), but I want to run my final app using pm2, or running node process.

I am using the Vuetify WebPack template (I'm using Vue.js), when I run the npm run build for production (in package.json: `“build”: “node build/build.js”`) the output is as follows:

```
$ ls
index.html static/
```

and

```
$ ls static/js/
app.f7301c212bc5fefd6563.js manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js vendor.1aae36aa0dc798d4d36d.js
app.f7301c212bc5fefd6563.js.map manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js.map vendor.1aae36aa0dc798d4d36d.js.map
```

So, how do I run this via node (npm start) or pm2 (pm2 start) (can't use index.html or static/js files).

When I run the webpack build I was expecting a .js output (for example ‘build.js’) to run via node or pm2 (npm start that runs ‘node build.js’ or pm2 start build.js). I suppose this will work for serverless, but was looking to run via pm2 (with nginx as proxy) as the app will have other factors (e.g., MongoDB) that won’t allow running in serverless (e.g., AWS Lambda).

Would this be a matter of just re-configuring WebPack to output to a .js file (for example, build.js), or will the static files (served via a webserver, nginx/Apache/http-server) allow for the same functionality? That is, will there be any factors that would limit my app by running as static verses via ‘node build.js’ or ‘pm2 start build.js’, (for example, will my API connects to the back-end still work (back-end being node/JS))?

Comment: Could you rewrite your question to me a little bit more clear? You just threw things on who is reading your question without properly asking something. 

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have a client-side Javascript app loaded into a user browser by fetching your index.html page. It's not clear from your question whether you have a server-side app (a node.js app) to run. Can you please [edit] your question to provide more detail about the structure of your app (server and client)?

Comment: Thanks much for taking the time to review. Question was hard to put into words. I updated the question above. Thanks.